# If url contains one of the strings, add css to the head

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to write a script which adds a stylesheet to the html document if it's url contains one of four possible strings

However, the code only works for urls which contain `string1` and none of the other strings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("string1"||"string2"||"string3"||"string4") > -1) {
    if (document.createStyleSheet) {
      document.createStyleSheet('path/to/css.css');
    }
    else {
      $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='path/to/css.css'/>"));
    }
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think `"string1"||"string2"||"string3"||"string4"` evaluates to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using a regular expression:

```
 if (window.location.href.match(/(string1|string2|string3|string4)/) != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
window.location.href.indexOf("string1"||"string2"||"string3"||"string4")
```

it first evaluates the argument

```
"string1"||"string2"||"string3"||"string4"
```

and passes the result of this to `indexOf()`. When you evaluate a sequence of `||` operators, it returns the first truthy value in the sequence, so your code is equivalent to

```
window.location.href.indexOf("string1")
```

If you want to compare with multiple strings, you need to combine the results of calling `indexOf()` on each one, you can't use `||` in the argument.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("string1") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("string2") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("string3") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("string4") > -1)
```

But a simpler way is to use a regular expression.

```
if (window.location.href.match(/string1|string2|string3|string4/)
```